# Sqlite analyze big table

Tags: python, sql, performance, sqlite, bigdata

i have tables in sqlite size of 649876358 line. I need get all lines with repetitive value in column and write every group in another file but sqlite working very slowing (after 10 minutes not one group not writed). What i have do for faster work?

I used python3 + sqlite

```py
db = sql.connect(path_to_db)
    
    with db:
        db_cursor = db.cursor()
    
    countLine = 649876358 #db_cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'T'").fetchall()[0][0]
    
    for i in range(1, countLine + 1):
        line = db_cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM 'T' WHERE ROWID = {i}", ).fetchall()[0]
        
        value = line[0]
        fileName = f"{path_to_save}{value}.json"
        
        if os.path.exists(fileName):
            continue

        allValue = db_cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM 'T' WHERE value = '{value}'").fetchall()
        
        if len(allValue) > 1:                        
            with open(fileName, "w") as file:
                json.dump(allValue, file)
```

Comment: Have you created indexes? Also, with 600M+ rows, you might consider a different SQL tool such as MySQL or PostgreSQL

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn’t do indexes, to be honest, I just needed a way to store data, in fact, I didn’t have time to really understand the database. I chose sqlite as the fastest and lightest that I could find and did not even suspect that the amount of data to process would be so large.

1: Is it possible to make indexes for an already finished table and how much will it increase the speed?

2: When switching to other SQL tools, will I need to somehow modify / rebuild the data?

Comment: 1) yes, you can 'CREATE INDEX' for tables with existing data, 2) run `sqlite3 yourdb .dump` and you'll get a bunch of INSERT statements you can use to populate a different database tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that would help but first of all I would add an index to your database:

```
create index your_index_name_here on your_table_name_here (your_column_name_here);
```

I just created a database with 3 columns id, name, number like this with 1 million lines (you have 600+ million lines):

```
1   R7N47UCYNE  363233
2   BFDXTROHVZ  273710
3   AVN6B8RCS7  949561
4   OHWTUCWDQW  863241
5   7F0B7UDJI4  791392
6   CV5TGBAQBJ  919640
7   PP8UF35C8J  897746
8   CN2J9ZAO63  671596
9   ZPM338I8QN  601521
10  12BFX9LXGE  845189
11  2NFP6DG299  858336
12  T5GH1V609M  692232
```

Searching for 10 names within my database before the index looked like this:

```
# (1999841, 'K6IWJK0MNP', 500224)
# (1715030, 'RY0N5VO9UM', 148000)
# (1999694, '474R4EMI3T', 705184)
# (1999539, 'L2YYGSLMUH', 943698)
# (1999425, 'UT352CDTQH', 828853)
# (1714958, 'KKAQ36DZGV', 279517)
# (1714905, 'BZ9CNWL5LS', 320070)
# (1714877, '6X7WCBBIZF', 247905)
# (1714839, '4MSV61HY9I', 263813)
# (1714806, '7NSRANTWEP', 476828)
# Finished in 1.3834 seconds
```

After the index was created:

```
# (1999841, 'K6IWJK0MNP', 500224)
# (1715030, 'RY0N5VO9UM', 148000)
# (1999694, '474R4EMI3T', 705184)
# (1999539, 'L2YYGSLMUH', 943698)
# (1999425, 'UT352CDTQH', 828853)
# (1714958, 'KKAQ36DZGV', 279517)
# (1714905, 'BZ9CNWL5LS', 320070)
# (1714877, '6X7WCBBIZF', 247905)
# (1714839, '4MSV61HY9I', 263813)
# (1714806, '7NSRANTWEP', 476828)
# Finished in 0.0006 seconds
```

Your can also set up a multiple cursors to do the second search rather than do a count/range.  Your first query could be:

```
select_all = "SELECT * FROM your_table"
rows = cursor.execute(select_all).fetchall()
for row in rows:
    value = row[0]
    .....etc etc
```

Then use the results to generate the a second query:

```
allValue = cursor2.execute(f"SELECT * FROM 'T' WHERE value = '{value}'").fetchall()
```

Finally SQLite might not be the best database to work with for this volume of rows.  You could use a more performant database and dump the SQLite one to something like MariaDB:

```
sqlite3 sample.db .dump > dump.sql
```

Then into your new database with a command like:

```
mysql -p -u root -h 127.0.0.1 newdb < dump.sql
```